# Mapping drives on MacOSX (Leopard/Snow Leopard) permanently inside LAN

Tags: mac-osx, bash, network-share, osx-snow-leopard, mappeddrive

How do I "map" shared folders on a Mac, permanently? With map, I do not mean 'connect', but permanently add it to the system so it exists after reboot. Since workstations tend to shutdown, I wonder also the symptoms and cures in case that happens. In Linux, this can be done using the fstab file, but I noticed that volumes are mounted in a different structure than Linux. I need this to backup some workstations, doing a recursive job over a single directory, that should contain the shared folders. I use Terminal to access the main system, so by preference, the solution would be nice that works within a bash shell vs GUI. I can access all folders in Finder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out [Autofs: Automatically
Mounting Network File
Shares in Mac OS X](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/Autofs.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do that.
Please take a look at this article.

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20100403050702737